# Sending HTML email via Gmail API results in messages with markup in plain text

Tags: c#, email, gmail, html-email

I'm trying to set up a server that, among other things, processes registrations.  It's the standard process that everyone's familiar with: get username, password, and email address, then send a confirmation mail to the address with a link containing a token that will activate the account.

Putting links inside an email means doing the email in HTML, which, as I understand it, is done by setting a content-type header value in the email.  I have a gmail account set up to do the sending from, and when I test it by registering an account for myself, I do get an email... but it's a plain-text email full of HTML markup.

Here's the code I'm using to send the email:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1;
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;

namespace MyProject.Mail {
    class GMailClient
    {
        private readonly GmailService _service;

        public GMailClient(UserCredential credential)
        {
            var initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer { HttpClientInitializer = credential};
            _service = new GmailService(initializer);
        }

        public async Task SendMail(string sender, string recipient, string subject, string body) {
            var fullMessage = $@"To: {recipient}
From: {sender}
Subject: {subject}
Content-Type: text/html; charset=""utf-8""

{body}";
            var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fullMessage);
            var b64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes).TrimEnd('=').Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_');
            var message = new Message
            {
                Raw = b64,
                SizeEstimate = body.Length
            };
            await _service.Users.Messages.Send(message, "me").ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(true);
        }
    }
}
```

The weirdest thing is, the plain-text email I receive isn't the plain HTML text I sent out.  The HTML message I'm sending looks like this:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <p>Hi,
      <p>You're receiving this because you recently signed up for a MyProject account.  Here's your confirmation link: <a href="url here">url here</a>.
      <p> If you did not sign up for a MyProject account, please simply ignore this email.
   </body>
</html>
```

But the message I'm actually receiving in my inbox looks like this:

> < head > < body > < p > Hi, < p > You're receiving this because you recently signed up for a MyProject account.  Here's your confirmation link: [url here, *actually formatted as a hyperlink*] < p > If you did not sign up for a MyProject account, please simply ignore this email.

(Note the strange whitespace and the lack of closing tags, among other things.)

This is confusing the heck out of me.  Any idea what's going wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: when you create the message var message = new Message
            {
                Raw = b64,
                SizeEstimate = body.Length
            }; you need to add isbodyhtml = true;

Comment: @jonaChaz Huh?  [The Message class](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Gmail_1_1v1_1_1Data_1_1Message.html#af6653b5368f7885cd8a3826dc28cb938) doesn't look like it has a property called `isbodyhtml`.

Comment: then you need to close your p tags maybe?

Comment: Note sure if it&#39;s right but it seems your character set and body are sitting outside the variable `fullMessage`?

Comment: @syfer It's a multiline string.

Comment: I dont do C++ but multi line string don't go in a line? `charset=""utf-8""` I have a feeling your character set is not coming through. Maybe I am wrong. I will stop right here. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @Syfer I don't do C++ either.  This is C#; the `@` prefix makes it a multi-line string, and doubling up the double-quotes escapes them.